# Microservice grouping of modules

Tags: soa, microservices

I'm developing an Employee Management System and following a microservice-style architecture. Initially, I have created the ERD and designed several master maintenance tables like Department, Project, Position etc...

My question is do I have to create a single service for each of these tables? or should I create a single service called master maintenance for all these tables?

Please help me to decide. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's a very abstract question. Are you asking for a design pattern for your scenario? Could you make the question more concrete?

Comment: I would like to know what would be the best practice, for example I have 100 tables that is not part of the transaction but it's there for CRUD operations, does it mean I have to create 100 microservices?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term, master maintenance table. Is it a table thats not a look up table but rather a table that actually has meaningful domain values?

Comment: Master maintenance is not a table, it's a collection of tables that has basic CRUD operation but not part of transaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second tennet of SOA states:

> Services are [autonomous](http://serviceorientation.com/serviceorientation/service_autonomy)

What this means is that as much as possible, there should be no horizontal coupling between services. Taking a specific example from your question, the Department service should not be coupled to the Projects service.

However, by modelling both department and projects data within a single database, you are already introducing coupling between them.

To decouple your services then, you should give each service it's own database. Services would then have to communicate via some other mechanism to exchange data with each other, rather than via the database.

However, this approach introduces complexity into your solution. This is known as the *[microservice premium](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/MicroservicePremium.html)*. You should ask yourself if this cost is worth the benefit of a microservice-based approach, at least to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for the input, now I have an Idea what to do with my question.